# Force Docker:Jellyfin to use existing config data on Synology

Tags: docker, nas, synology, kodi

i previously ran jellyfin on my desktop comuputer and put a lot of work into the manual creation of collection (descriptions, folder pictures etc.). Now i want to implement jellyfin on my brandnew Synology DS220+ NAS, which is running Jellyfin on Docker. If my understanding of Docker is correct, it is running an instance of the jellyfin app. So while its running, i am not able to see the folders/files of jellyfin in my FileStation-Browser.

So my question is: How can i force Jellyfin/Docker to use the existing Jellyfin-Collection-Data from my desktopPC (which are bacically .xml files).

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to map filepaths for config, cache and media. From the jellyfin docs:

```
docker run -d -v /srv/jellyfin/config:/config -v /srv/jellyfin/cache:/cache -v /media:/media --net=host jellyfin/jellyfin:latest
```

Arguments of -v flag means volume mapping. Left of colon(:) is your machine's path while right side is the path viewed by jellyfin in its container.
If you don't map internal volumes of a container with your machine, you cannot view those files and the data created will be destroyed on container shutdown.

So basically replace the config,cache and media paths of the above command with your folder paths

Comment: When i type in the code (with "\\servername\folder1\subfolder1\old_config_folder) it says `bash: docker: command not found` in the docker-terminal

Comment: Is docker installed on your machine ? is `docker run hello-world` working ?

Comment: I cant type in the inital Terminal-Window when starting the docker container. Only by adding a new terminal-tab. In this one it says `root@dockername:/#`. -> `docker run hello-world` gives the same output as above

Answer (score 0):

The `docker run hello-world` by @vanshaj is ment to be executed in the terminal window (ssh session) and not in a docker container.

Another approach would be to install the jellyfin package of synocommunity.com. This package does not use docker and is available since just a few days ago.